# Limit cores per job in sun gridengine

Tags: sungridengine

I'm currently setting up a gridengine on Ubuntu 16.04 using the sun gridengine.
Most of the features I want to use are working. However, I'm struggling with the following problem:

- I have a 32 core machine (64 threads)
- I'm running jobs which use software like Matlab...
- These software packages can use multiple threads for calcultion

Current situation:
The Queue has 2 slots, Processors is set to 1.
I submit one job and all 64 threads are used for the calculation.
I submit a second job and both are running in parallel.
So, for run time test, I cannot control the number of used cores.

I also tried to setup a parallel environment (connected to that queue). But also if I run a job there, all cores are used.

I guess I have a general understanding problem.

Does anybody know or have an idea, how it is possible to setup something like that:

a) each slot can only use one core (then the parallel environment would allow me to specify the slots/cores of a job

b) to restrict the cores of a submitted job

Important is also that it is not only an upper but also a lower bound. But this could be handled by the number of slots, I guess.

Thanks already in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't(easily) control the number of threads a process can spawn but,using a recent grid engine, you can control the number of cores it can access.  If your grid engine is recent check out the -binding parameter of qsub and the USE_CGROUPS option in sge_conf.  If you have an older grid engine then you could try playing tricks with the starter_method.

Comment: Not specifically limiting number of threads, but I managed to create a shell script using cpulimit (`cpulimit --limit 100 --include-children "$@"`) and the starter_method to force all jobs to run within this script for a given queue (`qconf -rattr queue starter_method /full/path/limit_cpu.sh my_queue.q`) to limit the CPU each job uses.